# How to convert xml Document into NSString in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-serialization

I am creating  xml in ios , that is correct (print on log) , but when i convert the `xmlDocument` in to `NSString` , string contain null when i print in log , sting is require as parameter of webservice , , how to assign `xmlDocument` to `NSString` ... thanks ..

> my code is ...

```
GDataXMLElement *rootElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"Root"];

GDataXMLElement *zipCode = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"zipCode" stringValue:self
                            .tfZipcode.text];
GDataXMLElement *phoneNo = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"phoneNo" stringValue:self.tfPhone.text];
GDataXMLElement *cellNo = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"cellNo" stringValue:self.tfCell.text];

GDataXMLElement *city = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"city" stringValue:self.tfCity.text];
GDataXMLElement *zone = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"zone" stringValue:self.tfZone.text];
GDataXMLElement *firstName = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"firstName" stringValue:self.tfFirstName.text];
GDataXMLElement *lastName = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"lastName" stringValue:self.tfLastName.text];
GDataXMLElement *address = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"address" stringValue:self.tfAddress.text];
GDataXMLElement *email = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:self.tfEmail.text];

GDataXMLElement *service = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"service" stringValue:self.tfService.text];
GDataXMLElement *product = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"product" stringValue:self.tfProduct.text];
GDataXMLElement *symptom = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"symptom" stringValue:self.tfSymptoms.text];
GDataXMLElement *jobType = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"jobType" stringValue:self.tfJobType.text];
GDataXMLElement *ref = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"ref" stringValue:self.tfRef.text];
GDataXMLElement *reqDate = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"reqDate" stringValue:self.tfDateTime.text];


[rootElement addChild:zipCode];
[rootElement addChild:phoneNo];
[rootElement addChild:cellNo];
[rootElement addChild:city];
[rootElement addChild:zone];
[rootElement addChild:firstName];
[rootElement addChild:lastName];
[rootElement addChild:address];
[rootElement addChild:email];
[rootElement addChild:service];
[rootElement addChild:product];
[rootElement addChild:symptom];
[rootElement addChild:jobType];
[rootElement addChild:ref];
[rootElement addChild:reqDate];

GDataXMLDocument *xml = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithRootElement:rootElement];
NSLog(@"%@", [xml rootElement]);   // print xml on log



NSString *stringXml = [xml rootElement];

NSLog(@"%@",stringXml);
```

Comment: I guess some problem in encoding.

Comment: i print xmlDocument on log , that is correct .. but how to convert xmlDocument to NSString ? that is my Question .. thanks

Comment: Do you want to print GDataXMLDocument directly ?

Comment: did u try my answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  NSString *stringXml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [xml rootElement]];

  NSLog(@"%@",stringXml);
```

Comment: yap , it assign to string ,, but webservice give me error ,, 400

Comment: how you are constructing the request

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
NSString * YOURSTRING = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[xml rootElement] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",YOURSTRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach, otherwise, you'll lose the xml element, thus the xml version and document encoding.

```
GDataXMLDocument * xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithRootElement:rootElement];

[xmlDocument setVersion:@"1.0"];
[xmlDocument setCharacterEncoding:@"UTF-8"];

NSString *xmlDocumentRepresentation = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlDocument.XMLData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"xml %@", xmlDocumentRepresentation);
```

Answer (score -1):

you should try this way, more easy:

```
NSString *yourXMLString = [[GDataXMLDocument rootElement] xmlString];
```

I use this way lots. Good luck!